# Java: Filtering out user input using nextInt()

Tags: java

I am making a program where the user enters their mark, if they enter over 100 then the program stops, however I can't seem to stop the value over 100 also being assigned to the Marks variable...

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Int Marks = 0;

while (Marks >= 0 && Marks <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Enter Students Test Marks Here");

        Marks = input.nextInt();
}

// Output Test
System.out.println("The Marks variable value is " +Marks);
```

Comment: There is not type as `Int` in Java.

Comment: you have to specify the error: compilation or runtime, the text of it and so on

Comment: With your loop conditions, `Marks` will only be printed if it is over 100 or under 0, as your loop won't stop otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the condition backwards! `while` executes **while** the condition is true, not **until** the condition is true... So, what you need to do instead is this:

```
int marks = -1; // Start with an "illegal" marks value

while ((marks<0) || (marks>100)) { // while we have an illegal mark ...
    System.out.println("Enter Students Test Marks Here (0..100)");

    marks = input.nextInt(); // ... ask for a new one
}
```

After this, your marks variable contains a valid number between 0 and 100.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed... You didn't ask about prompting the user until he enters a correct value, but running the program until he enters a wrong value and merely preventing the assignment to the `Marks` variable... If that is indeed what you are after, you can do this:

```
int marks = 0;

while (true) { // Just keep running
    System.out.println("Enter Students Test Marks Here (<0 or >100 to quit)");
    int newMark = input.nextInt();
    if ((newMark<0) || (newMark>100)) break; // Skip out of while loop
    marks = newMark; // Only happens if newMark is between 0 and 100
}
```

You can also replace the `break` part with `return` to exit not only the while loop, but the function in which it is called, or maybe even `System.exit(0)`, if you want to quit the program immediately.

But the trick would be to use a temporary variable to check the input before assigning it to marks.

(BTW: As a convention, variable names in Java usually start with a lower-case letter...)

Comment: Thanks very much, this answers my question, really appreciate all the help people, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The moment you enter the value greater 100 you are inside:

```
while (Marks >= 0 && Marks <= 100) {
    System.out.println("Enter Students Test Marks Here");

    Marks = input.nextInt();}
```

So the Value is assigned to `Marks` and that is when your `while` stops, so it will be printed in the last line:

`System.out.println("The Marks variable value is " +Marks);`

A possible solution could be:

```
boolean done = true;
int marks;
while(done == true){
    System.out.println("Enter Student Test Marks Here");
    if(input.nextInt() <= 0 || input.nextInt() >= 100){
        done = false;
    }else{
        marks = input.nextInt();
    }
}

System.out.println("The Marks variable value is " + marks);
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, but what I fail to understand is why the while part of the code will not filter out any values over 100 which have been entered?

Comment: Because you enter the `while` loop BEFORE entering the `value`. The while loop will then exit BECAUSE a value greater then 100 was assigned to `Marks`.

Comment: I think with this code, the user will be prompted THREE TIMES for a new value (once for each input.nextInt()), two of which are discarded and only used for the if-check and one is actually assigned to marks, but isn't checked... This code would fail miserably...

Comment: Sry for that, assigning `input.nextInt()` to a temporary variable before checking the if-clause would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

what bout this?

```
         Marks = input.nextInt();
 while (Marks >= 0 && Marks <= 100) {
    System.out.println("Enter Students Test Marks Here");

    Marks = input.nextInt();
}
```